# Giving WordPress its own subdirectory - nginx

Tags: htaccess, installation, server, nginx

I want to move WordPress installation to a subdirectory without affecting site url - https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/ (method 1)

The article contains only instructions for Apache2. How would it translate to nginx site configuration?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can't you just point the URL to the subdirectory? Then no change would be required.

Comment: Yes, changing the document root (`root` directive) on Nginx would be the preferred solution (since on Nginx you are having to modify the server config anyway). Unless... you are wanting to serve other content (outside of WordPress) from the document root also (which these Apache directives would allow you to do)? @kero

Comment: @MrWhite Then just change the `root` for these specific resources? You can easily do so within a `location` block e.g. Or use a subdomain for them (aka another `server` block).